# php lifetime of cookie set to 1 results in unnatural date in browser?

Tags: php, session, browser, lifetime, setcookie

As in theme setting lifetime of cookie to value 1 or 10 appears in strange result of year of date in cooke in browser, as follows:

```
setcookie(cookie_name, 'logout', 1, cookie_path, cookie_domain, cookie_secure, cookie_httponly );
```

1. on 1 5838270
2. on 10 5838270
3. on 1000 the same

Didn't check with others, but it is strange result, why ?

Comment: Which PHP version as the cookie setting code has changed quite a bit over the years? 
https://github.com/php/php-src/blame/master/ext/standard/head.c#L157

Comment: Can you post the raw HTTP header that is being sent? The numbers you are showing appear to be timestamps which wouldn’t be valid for expiration

Comment: Where You see timestamp ? There is setting lifetime with value = 1. All is clear.

Comment: Sorry, being an integer, `5838270` looked like a timestamp, I’m probably wrong. Still, please explain when you say “on 1 5838270” what that means, including proof from HTTP which defines this

Comment: As I checked with other lifetime value set to time() results the same strange behavior. 5838270 is the Year visible in cookie lifetime in browser and 20 September...

Comment: Sorry to keep bugging you, but can you show the HTTP header itself that is being sent, either raw or a screenshot, as opposed to the browser’s interpretation of it

Comment: No problem, it is some tip to check this. I will check this soon. How to check this ? With what functions ?

Comment: Thanks @DarofromPoland. At a quick glance everything looks good with your header, and although it uses the older date format, it is still technically valid, so I agree this might be on the browser side.